# Convert Pytorch model into Tensorflow, loading .pb file problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I work on TF 2.11 and python3.8

I tried to convert pytorch model (best.pt)  to TF light as the documentation says

I used the command:

```
export.py --weights runs/train/exp/weights/best.pt --include tflite  --img 416 --data dataset/custom.yaml
```

So, I get a folder named "best_saved_model" with .pb file and one .tflight file

While I am loading the saved_model.pb into my code :

```
frozen_graph_path = args.model_path
saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(frozen_graph_path, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
```

I get an error, why is this happening?
Isn't the .pb file the converted Tensorflow model?

Comment: "I get an error" – _what error_?